# Where are the files located on the tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat

I have a very noob question :)
I have a file in [myip]/folder1/folder2/file.js, that I can access and read using a browser.

Where can I find this file on my computer? I need to edit it...

Searching for the file on my computer yields no results :(

Thanks

Comment: I should have probably mentioned it, but I'm working on windows 7...

Answer (score 2):

You should not be editing the files that you have deployed to your local tomcat server.  Instead you should edit the files in you development environment then redeploy your web application.

You should have a CATALINA_HOME environment variable set to the install location of tomcat.  Deployed web applications are under the webapps directory.  So your file would be in $CATALINA_HOME\webapps\myip\folder1\folder2\file.js, but don't edit it there.

Comment: +1 - "You should not be editing the files that you have deployed to your local tomcat server" - this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's located in the ROOT of your Tomcat server, in folder1/folder2.

Comment: shouldn't it be `<tomcat_root>/webapps/'folder1'/'folder2'`?